# Scheduling problem: Does this have a name?

Tags: algorithm, scheduling, weighted

I have the following problem:

There are *N* items *A(n)* and associated weights *W(n)* for *n*=0...*N*-1.

Generate a sequence *S(t)* (where *t*= 0,1,2,3,...,*T-1*) of items chosen from *A(n)* such that:

- Adjacent symbols in the sequence are not equal:

  *S(t)* != *S(t-1)*
- The *W(n)* describe the frequency of occurrence of *A(n)* in *S* over duration *T*:

  *W(n)* / sum (*k* = 0...*N*-1) *W(k)* = sum (*t*=0...*T-1*) **indicator** ( *S(t)* == *A(n)* ) / *T*

  where **indicator**(*x*) is 0 if *x* is false and 1 if *x* is true.

Does this sort of problem have a name other than weighted scheduling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be related to the term "cyclic executive". Take a look and let me know if this is heading in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, that looks very close!  I'll leave this question open overnight to see if anyone else chimes in.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas! That got me where I wanted.

Comment: Heh, I'm glad it helped... Sorry I couldn't give more/better help, though. :)